# Re-name [fpvcamera] tag to use spacing

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Can the tag [fpvcamera](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fpvcamera) be renamed to [fpv-camera](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fpv-camera) to use proper spacing, when trying to edit it myself I get this message:

> [image]

Can a moderator please re-name it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just created a synonym and merged the tags so [fpv-camera](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fpv-camera) is the master tag.